# GCD dispatch_async for app-lifetime task?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I've used GCD before with `dispatch_async` for background-threading units of work like parsing data from a network request (in, say, JSON or XML), and it's WONDERFUL.  But what if I have a background task that's going to run for the length of the application?  Is `dispatch_async` still a good fit for this case, or is there a better way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but create your own dispatch queue for it. (If you use a global queue, you may tie up that queue--or one of its threads--forever.)

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myapp.ForeverOperation", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^{
    // worker routine 
});
```

More traditionally, you would create an explicit thread for this, and if it will run forever, that might make more "sense". But the results are basically the same.

```
NSThread * myWorkerThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:...
[myWorkerThread start];
```

If you need to communicate with other threads/queues, as always, standard synchronization techniques may be required.

Comment: Some homework indicates that custom queues will get their target queue set by default to the global default priority queue, which means that work submitted to the custom queue will execute on the global one.  So what is the advantage of creating the custom queue when I will execute on the global one anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This really has nothing to do with `dispatch_async`, which is merely one approach to doing something in a background thread. If you want to do something in a background thread, do it in a background thread! Just be aware that doing this constantly can be a drag on your app, since you've only got so much processing time and only so many processors; you may end up having to study that in Instruments. You might want to break up your task into little bits and do it in short chunks every so often. Both GCD and NSOperation can help with that.